# Qt - QTreeView starts behaving strangely over time of running the application

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator

I have a weird problem.
After the application starts, everything works normally.
However after some time, QTreeViews in my application start behaving weird. The selection is no longer system-blue. Instead, it looks like

[click to see pictures 1), 2), 3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgWpb.png)

I.e, there's a slight dim over the icon and dotted lines to the left and to the right, as on picture **1)**. The "expand" triangle in Windows 8.1 turns into a +/- button, as on picture **2)**. And when i hover mouse over this expand button, I am getting an empty white square instead of a "highlighted expansion triangle", as on picture **3)**.

Normally, the selection and the expansion triangle should look like this (which it does after the application start) as shown on picture **1)** below

[click to see pictures 1), 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tb5Wn.png)

And the mouse hovered expansion triangle should look like on picture **2)** (which it does after app start).

The application is launched with administrator privileges on Windows 8.1.

Interestingly the QtCreator 4.0.0 for Qt 5.6.0 (which I am using) sometimes starts having the same problem in its file tree view (where the project files are listed). I run it with administrator privileges as well (because I  need to debug my app that requires admin privileges).

What can be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a known bug and that it is fixed in Qt5.6.1 release. [See here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-52230) for details of the bug - it looks like what you are seeing (or very similar).

So try to updating to Qt5.6.1 and see if this resolves it.

Comment: Thank you, looks like this was it

Comment: @O.W.Grant no prob... should have said, I think the latest verion is 5.7.x so you can jump straight to that!